# Creating a dictionary with inline explanation using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress plugin to search text for specific words from a custom dictionary and then I want to make the explanation appear in a sidebar at the height/place where the word is found.

Right now I've got a function which searches for the word, and places the word in the sidebar, but it's not at the right height of the text. The words just appear at the top of my sidebar.

The statement I use to get the words from the text is basically this:

```
if (stripos( $content, ' '.$title.' ') != false){
    $words[$word->ID][$word->post_title] = $word->post_content;
}
```

After that I use a loop to return a HTML string which contains the words that have been found in the text, this HTML string is placed in the sidebar.

Comment: It doesnt sound like the issue is with this statement? Is it not more an issue of where you are echoing out $words ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right! But since I'm just echoing those words, I thought it would not be helpful to write down my echo $word; Right now I'm looking for a statement/ a way to make the words echo/appear at a place in my sidebar which is at the same "height" as the word in the text.

Comment: Could you not just echo it out in to the same div? Sorry if this is not helpful, maybe some visuals of what it looks like now would help?

Comment: @BenLonsdale If you open this http://www.wearesicc.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/bootstrap-reorder-11.png you see 3 columns. Column 1 is where the main navigation is, column 3 is where the text is. I am looking for a way to explain words, that are difficult to understand, in column 2. So if someone reads a difficult word in the middle column, I want the explanation of that word to show up in a column on the right of it, at the same height. Since it's a website with 50+ (and counting) pages, I want the script to automatically put the words on the right place.

Comment: Right now I have managed to get those "difficult words" to be echoed in the most right column, but not at the right point of the text. I hope you understand me, otherwise I will post another visual.

Comment: I understand the issue now, I'm having a think about it. Might have to sleep on it. I'll post back here tomorrow, in the mean time let me know if you solve it :)

Comment: @BenLonsdale Allright! Thank you, I did not solve it yet.